# Printing multiple images each on a separate page using single NSPrintOperation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, printing

I have a application that intends to print raster image of each page of a document using `NSPrintOperation`. I am able to create a `NSImage` of a single page and print it using `NSPrintOperation` as follows

```
-void printPage:(NSImage)nsImage
{
    NSImageView *nsImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
    NSSize imageSize = [nsImage size];
    [nsImageView setImage:(NSImage *)nsImage];
    [nsImageView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
    [nsImageView setImageScaling:NSScaleToFit];

    NSPrintOperation *mNSPrintOperation = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:(NSView *)nsImageView];

    NSPrintInfo *currentNSPrintInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
    [currentNSPrintInfo setHorizontalPagination:NSFitPagination];
    [currentNSPrintInfo setVerticalPagination:NSFitPagination];

    [mNSPrintOperation setPrintInfo:currentNSPrintInfo];
    [mNSPrintOperation setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
    [mNSPrintOperation setShowsProgressPanel:YES];

    [mNSPrintOperation runOperation];
}
```

Now when I have multiple pages to print, I would like to print all of them using a single `NSPrintOperation`. So basically, I would like to insert `NSImage/NSImageView` of each page as a separate page into a single `NSView` and use this `NSView` to print finally using `NSPrintOperation`. The reason I want to print it using single `NSPrintOperation` is that I want to get the print progress bar that shows the current page being printed. Otherwise, I could have created a separate `NSPrintOperation` for each `NSImageView` and print using it.